# Camel-Netty4 TCP connection configuration

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I'm facing connection refused exception while trying to connect through TCP even in localhost by using camel-netty4.

```
<route id="test-producer">
    <from uri="quartz://{{t1tos.promis.containerupdate.job.detail}}" /> 
    <to uri="bean:haSessionProcessor?method=getHAStatus" />
    <log message="Server Status ::: ${body}"/>
    <to uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:9001??textline=true&amp;sync=true"/>
    <log message="Server Status ::: ${body}"/> 
</route>

<route id="test-consumer">
    <from uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:9001clientMode=true&amp;sync=true&amp;textline=true"/>
    <log message="Invert Server Status ::: ${body}"/>
</route>
```

Please advice to resolve the issue, I'm not able to find a working example for this. Do I need to configure host address and port number.

Comment: your from-uri needs a `?` before options - `netty4:tcp://localhost:9001?clientMode=true`

Comment: Do you have a TCP service running on port 9001 that can process the requests from Camel? The 2nd route is not setting up a server because you have turned on client mode.

Comment: Thank you very much @ClausIbsen and spinlok, your input helped a lot to resolve the issue. I'm wrong in connecting to unavailable port. Thanks a lot.